# Laravel 8 - Get Visitors User Details

Tags: laravel

hoping something can help. I've been struggling with this one for a while and not sure if its something obvious that I am missing.

I have a user profile setup, where when someone views it, it stores the user id of that person in a table. I would like to create a "Who's visited me" where it will show the user details of that person who has visited their profile.

So far everything is working but I cannot get the Who's visited me working to show the details.

Here is what I have so far

**User Model**

```
    public function profile()
{
    return $this->hasOne(Profile::class);
}

public function profileViews(){

    return $this->hasMany(ProfileView::class, 'profile_id');
}
```

**ProfileView Model**

```
protected $fillable = [
    'profile_id',
    'visitor_id',
];

public function users()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
}
```

**Profile Controller**

```
public function profile(User $user)
{
    $profile_id = $user->id;
    
    ProfileView::updateOrCreate(['visitor_id' => Auth::user()->id, 'profile_id' => $profile_id,  'updated_at' => now()]);
    
    return view('members.users.profile', compact('user' ));
}
```

Just incase you need it, my migration for the Profile Visitors Tables

**Profile View Table**

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('profile_views', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->id();
        $table->unsignedBigInteger('visitor_id');
        $table->unsignedBigInteger('profile_id');
        $table->timestamps();

        $table->foreign('visitor_id')
            ->references('id')
            ->on('users')
            ->onDelete('cascade');

    });
}
```

Here is what I have in the Who has visited me (this is where I am struggling so was playing about

```
    @foreach(Auth::user()->profileViews as $view)
  {<li>{{ $view->user->name }} </li>}
@endforeach
```

Comment: try like 
public function profileViews(){

    return $this->hasMany(ProfileView::class, 'visitor_id','profile_id');
}

Comment: `updateOrCreate` takes 2 arguments (first: attributes to search for, 2nd: values to update), you will just keep creating a new record with what you have since you are searching with a time stamp that won't match

Comment: I missed the updateOrCreate. @lagbox is relationship is correct?

Comment: the relationship method name should be `user` (singular) not `users` (plural) btw and you would have to define the key that is being used since it isn't `user_id`; in this case `visitor_id` .... also is the `profileViews` relationship working? how would it know the `profile_id` for the User?

Comment: the `profile_id` is the User's `id`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So we only have two models here, `User` and `Profile`, with a [many-to-many relationship](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many). `ProfileView` is actually just a pivot between the two, so a class definition isn't needed. But assuming the timestamp is something you'd like to get access to, you'll need to [make allowances for that](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#retrieving-intermediate-table-columns).

I'd suggest something like this:

```php
class User extends Model {
    public function profile() {
        return $this->hasOne(Profile::class);
    }
}

class Profile extends Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model {
    public function user() {
        return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
    }
    public function views() {
        return $this->hasMany(User::class, 'profile_views', 'profile_id', 'visitor_id')
            ->withPivot('created_at');
    }
}
```

Now, to add a profile view you can edit your controller method like this (I assume the `$user` is the user whose profile is being viewed.) Rather than creating an instance of the pivot, you [attach](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#updating-many-to-many-relationships) the relationship. I've detached previous relationships, assuming you only want to keep the most recent one.

```php
public function profile(User $user)
{
    $user->profile->views()->detach(Auth::id());
    $user->profile->views()->attach(Auth::id());

    return view('members.users.profile', compact('user'));
}
```

And to retrieve the information:

```html
<ul>
@foreach(Auth::user()->profile->views as $view)
  <li>{{ $view->name }} @ {{ $view->pivot->created_at }} </li>
@endforeach
</ul>
```

This is all a bit verbose due to your naming not matching Laravel conventions, and your choice to store `profile_id` in the pivot table instead of `user_id` but should do what you need.